# C# console logging: will it have memory issues?

Tags: c#, windows, logging, console

So I'm working with a console app that will persist for days, weeks, or months at a time.

It logs useful information to a text file, but it also writes to the Console. Do I have to worry about the console memory not getting purged for some reason. It seems to be okay.

I wrote a little test to run over lunch. I added some randomly spaced letters so that my coworkers think I must be processing something large and can take a longer lunch.

```
for (Int64 i = 0; i < 1000000000000000000; i++)
            {
                string random = Path.GetRandomFileName();
                random = random.Replace(".", "");
                random = random.Replace("m", "               ");
                random = random.Replace("a", "                                  ");
                random = random.Replace("h", "                         ");


                Console.WriteLine("i " + i + "   " + random);

            }
```

So, memory looks stable without writing to a file. I just want some confirmation that if I do have a memory issue, it's not from the console...

Memory does climb ever so slightly if I log it to a text file as well.

Comment: If it's genuinely useful information and it's going to take more than a handful of minutes to run and a human to digest that information, log it somewhere other than the console.

Comment: +1 for writing a program that lengthens lunch break

Comment: @48klocs I have a separate detailed log that outputs miniscule things like file paths, execution time and timestamps etc. The main console just shows progress in the cycle, what phase it's in and totals of attempts and errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It logs useful information to a text file, but it also writes to the Console. Do I have to worry about the console memory not getting purged for some reason. It seems to be okay.

Not unless you have your console set up to have an *enormous* buffer, or it's redirected to an in-memory file system, or something like that. In normal situations, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not an issue, any text that scrolls off the console buffer as specified by Console.SetBufferSize() falls in the bit-bucket.  The maximum buffer size is 64KB, a restriction that the Console class forgets to check btw.